# Synology FileStation API Can't Authorize

Tags: api, synology

I’m trying to test the Synology API using Postman.  So far however I can’t get the ‘sid’ to work.  I can authenticate and receive a ‘sid’, but any requests using it return a 403.

DSM Version - DSM 6.2.3-25426 Update 2

**Authenticate**
`/webapi/auth.cgi?api=SYNO.API.Auth&version=3&method=login&account={account}&passwd={password}&session=FileStation&format=sid`

I copy the ‘sid’ in the response.

**Info**
`/webapi/FileStation/entry.cgi?api=SYNO.FileStation.Info&version=1&_sid={sid}`

This returns a 403.  Any request I make with the ‘sid’ fails.  I have also tried using the `format=cookie` option, but it is the same result.

Would love to know if you know something that would point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

I've figured out why this was not working (was having the same issue), in your request for FileStation Info, you are making a request to `/webapi/FileStation/entry.cgi`, but it should actually be `/webapi/entry.cgi`, so the full request would be `/webapi/entry.cgi?api=SYNO.FileStation.Info&version=1&_sid={sid}`

You can see this is the correct path when making a request to: `/webapi/query.cgi?api=SYNO.API.Info&version=1&method=query&query=SYNO.FileStation.Info` as the path says it is `entry.cgi`. The API documentation is definitely a little misleading and would be good if it were updated.